# Mathematica ColorFunction behavior

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color

While trying to plot a figure, I ran into the following problem with *Mathematica*'s `ColorFunction` behavior.

Whereas

```
dFunction[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]

Plot3D[dFunction[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
    ColorData["ThermometerColors"][z]]]
```

returns me the image I want:

[image]

This:

```
Plot3D[dFunction[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
    ColorData["ThermometerColors"][dFunction[x, y]]]]
```

behaves very differently:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Have you seen `ColorFunctionScaling`?

Comment: Actually, it seems like when `ColorFunctionScaling` is set to `False` in both cases, I get the same figure. Would you mind explaining why?

Comment: you want `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` for both plots and they should be identical.  The default `True` normalizes the values it passes (all of them, x,y, & z)  to colorfunction to the range 0-1.  Note if the function you are plotting didn't happen to have a range 0-1 then it wouldn't look very good if you simply fed the value to `ColorData`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ColorFunctionScaling -> False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html)

```
dFunction[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]

Plot3D[dFunction[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["ThermometerColors"][z]]]

Plot3D[dFunction[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["ThermometerColors"][dFunction[x, y]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]